# T-SQL Multi-layered CTE query with Aggregates

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a long Common Table Expression (CTE) query which is trying to calculate percent difference between each users' average score and group average score.

I would like for my multi-layered CTE query to filter and reduce bulk of records down to the following table:

```
UserID     Tag     UserAvg     GroupAvg     PercentDifference
1          Cat     72.50       73           -0.68
2          Cat     75.50       73           3.36
3          Cat     75          73           2.70
4          Cat     73.25       73           0.34
5          Cat     52.3333     73           -32.97
6          Cat     86.25       73           16.64
```

My problem is getting `GroupAvg` column so that I can perform `% Difference` calculation.

To illustrate the current approach I am using; here is the summary of my CTE query:

```
WITH
-- select 1st 3 columns
UserScores    AS (select UserID, Tag, Score FROM {multiple-table} WHERE Tag = 'Cat'),
-- add UserAvg column by grouping records
ScoreAverages AS (select UserID, Tag, AVG(Score) AS UserAvg GROUP BY UserID, Tag FROM UserScores),
-- calculate GroupAvg
GroupAverage  AS (select AVG(UserAvg) AS GroupAvg FROM ScoreAverages),
-- calculate % difference
PercentDiff   AS (select UserID, Tag, UserAvg, 73 AS GroupAvg, (((UserAvg-73)/((UserAvg+73)/2))*100) AS PercentDifference FROM ScoreAverages )
-- do something with results
select * from PercentDiff
```

Simple enough; right?

Notice that I have hard coded `73` as my `GroupAvg` value. I am unsure how to construct required sql query that would allow me to go from `ScoreAverages` to `PercentDiff` table.

Is it possible to perform SELECT within a SELECT statement? And I am not looking for something of the following:

```
select * from X where Id in (select Id from Y where Name like '%abc%')
```

Or I am simply trying to do too much in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, as shown in Tab Alleman's answer, but in your case it's not necessary. Since you already calculate the `GroupAvg` in the cte chain, you can use it in the final query. and since the `GroupAverage` only contains one row, you can simply add a CROSS JOIN to it:

```
;WITH
-- select 1st 3 columns
UserScores    AS (
     select UserID, Tag, Score 
     FROM {multiple-table} 
     WHERE Tag = 'Cat'),
-- add UserAvg column by grouping records
ScoreAverages AS (
     select UserID, Tag, AVG(Score) AS UserAvg 
     FROM UserScores
     GROUP BY UserID, Tag),
-- calculate GroupAvg
GroupAverage  AS (
     select AVG(UserAvg) AS GroupAvg 
     FROM ScoreAverages),
-- calculate % difference
PercentDiff   AS (
     select UserID, Tag, UserAvg, GroupAvg, 
            (((UserAvg-GroupAvg)/((UserAvg+GroupAvg)/2))*100) AS PercentDifference 
     FROM ScoreAverages 
     CROSS JOIN GroupAverage)
-- do something with results
select * from PercentDiff
```

Comment: it would also be just as easy to use `AVG(Score) OVER() as GroupAvg` in the ScoreAverages cte

Comment: @JamieD77 but surely the ``ORDER BY`` clause would prevent you from doing that because ``Score`` is not a part of it?

Comment: @ZoharPeled your ``CROSS JOIN`` solution is perfect. Coincidently I was experimenting with joins just before I asked the question and I failed to test ``CROSS JOIN``. How silly of me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called a sub-select:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, (SELECT QUERY THAT GETS GROUP AVERAGE) AS GroupAverage, Column3
FROM ...
```

To use the result of the sub-select in another column's calculation, you can either repeat the sub-select:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, (SELECT QUERY THAT GETS GROUP AVERAGE) AS GroupAverage, (Column3 - (SELECT QUERY THAT GETS GROUP AVERAGE)) AS Column4
FROM ...
```

Or you can reference it the same as you would any other column in the outer query or a subsequent CTE:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT Column1, Column2, (SELECT QUERY THAT GETS GROUP AVERAGE) AS GroupAverage
FROM ...)
  , CTE2 AS (SELECT *, Column3-GroupAverage) AS Column4
  FROM CTE1
  JOIN ...
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. It is exactly what I was trying to achieve after my attempt with JOINs failed. I had to hand it to Zohar Peled as it yields a more elegant query.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought you could do this with a single cte like so.

```
;WITH UserAverages AS
(
    SELECT  UserID,
            Tag,
            AVG(Score) AS UserAvg,
            AVG(AVG(Score)) OVER () AS GroupAvg
    FROM    {multiple-table}
    WHERE   Tag = 'Cat'
    GROUP BY UserID, Tag
)
SELECT  UserID,
        Tag,
        UserAvg,
        GroupAvg,
        (((UserAvg-GroupAvg)/((UserAvg+GroupAvg)/2))*100) AS PercentDifference
FROM    UserAverages
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong the last time. As per your initial suggestion; I used  ``AVG(Score) OVER() as GroupAvg`` and SQL complained that ``Score`` is not part of ``GROUP BY``. Now that I've corrected my mistake it works. Very neat actually. Thank you for taking the time to post the answer.